# How can I pass a variable from one class to other without use a function in php?

Tags: php, function, parameters

I have `daoHistorial.php`:

```
 <?php

require "transferDao/daoTransferHistorial.php";

require "bdconnection.php";


    class daoHistorial{

            public function sqlSelect($tarea){

                    $aObjects=array();


                    $dbconn = new DBconnection();
                    $db = $dbconn->bdConnection();
                    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t1.tar_id, t1.rea_seccion, t1.rea_porcentaje, t1.rea_descripcion, t1.hrs_tarea, t1.tar_fechtermino 
                                          FROM act_registtarea t1
                                          inner join act_tarea t2
                                          ON t1.tar_id = t2.tar_id 
                                          where t2.tar_nombre = '$tarea'");
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                            $aTransfer = new daoTransferHistorial();
                            $aTransfer->setPorcentaje($row['rea_porcentaje']);
                            $aTransfer->setDescripcion($row['rea_descripcion']);
                            $aTransfer->setFechaTermino($row['tar_fechtermino']);
                            $aTransfer->setSeccion($row['rea_seccion']);
                            $aTransfer->setHora($row['hrs_tarea']);

                            $aObjects[]=$aTransfer;
                    }

                    print_r($aObjects);
                    return $aObjects;
            }   
    }
?>
```

And I have `controllerHistorial.php`:

```
<?php

require "dao/daoHistorial.php";  

class HistorialTareas {

    public function getHistorial() {

        $aTransfer = new daoHistorial();

        foreach($aTransfer->sqlSelect() as $sKey=>$oValue){    
            $list[] = array('porcentaje' => $oValue->getPorcentaje(),
                            'descripcion' => $oValue->getDescripcion(),
                            'fecha_termino' => $oValue->getFechaTermino(),
                            'seccion' =>$oValue->getSeccion(),
                            'hora' =>$oValue->getHora()
                            );
        }
        print_r($list);
        return $list;
    }
}

?>
```

here : `foreach($aTransfer->sqlSelect() as $sKey=>$oValue){` I have a problem for Missing argument with

> sqlSelect()

I need use `sqlSelect($tarea)` from `daoHistorial.php.

I know that I need pass the parameter in `public function getHistorial($tarea)`

But I need this :

```
public function getHistorial() {
$aTransfer = new daoHistorial();
foreach($aTransfer->sqlSelect($tarea) as $sKey=>$oValue){
```

because after I need `getHistorial()` without parameter.

Comment: Do you want the query in `sqlSelect` to run without the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: so sometimes you need to call `getHistorial()` with no params?  therefore leaving `sqlSelect()` parameter free?

Comment: Hi ,  I need the same variable $tarea from daoHistorial.php in controllerHisotrial.php : foreach($this->sqlSelect($tarea) as $sKey=>$oValue)  . there I want to use the variable, no in getHisotrial() , but i dont know how pass the variable and use  if i dont pass the parameter in getHistorial

Answer (score 1):

Update the relevant files to the following:

daoHistorial.php

```
<?php
require "transferDao/daoTransferHistorial.php";
require "bdconnection.php";

class daoHistorial{
    public $tarea = NULL;

    public function setTarea($val) {
        $this->tarea = $val;
    }

    public function sqlSelect() {
        $aObjects=array();

        $dbconn = new DBconnection();
        $db = $dbconn->bdConnection();

        $incStatement = ($this->tarea != NULL) ? "where t2.tar_nombre = '.$this->tarea.'":"";

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT t1.tar_id, t1.rea_seccion, t1.rea_porcentaje, t1.rea_descripcion, t1.hrs_tarea, t1.tar_fechtermino 
                                          FROM act_registtarea t1
                                          inner join act_tarea t2
                                          ON t1.tar_id = t2.tar_id 
                                          ".$incStatement);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach ($result as $row) {
                            $aTransfer = new daoTransferHistorial();
                            $aTransfer->setPorcentaje($row['rea_porcentaje']);
                            $aTransfer->setDescripcion($row['rea_descripcion']);
                            $aTransfer->setFechaTermino($row['tar_fechtermino']);
                            $aTransfer->setSeccion($row['rea_seccion']);
                            $aTransfer->setHora($row['hrs_tarea']);

                            $aObjects[]=$aTransfer;
         }

         print_r($aObjects);
         return $aObjects;
    }   
}
?>
```

controllerHistorial.php

```
<?php
require "dao/daoHistorial.php";  

class HistorialTareas extends daoHistorial {

    public function getHistorial() {

        foreach($this->sqlSelect() as $sKey=>$oValue){    
            $list[] = array('porcentaje' => $oValue->getPorcentaje(),
                            'descripcion' => $oValue->getDescripcion(),
                            'fecha_termino' => $oValue->getFechaTermino(),
                            'seccion' =>$oValue->getSeccion(),
                            'hora' =>$oValue->getHora()
                            );
        }
        print_r($list);
        return $list;
    }
}
?>
```

Now when accessing HistorialTareas, you can do this

```
<?php
$historial = new HistorialTareas;
$getData = $historial->getHistorial();
```

for normal results, or to filter

```
<?php
$historial = new HistorialTareas;
$historial->setTarea('VALUE HERE');
$getData = $historial->getHistorial();
```

Comment: Hi , I have this problem with your answer: 'Missing argument 1 for daoHistorial::sqlSelect() , I need the same variable $tarea from daoHistorial.php in controllerHisotrial.php : foreach($this->sqlSelect($tarea) as $sKey=>$oValue) , sorry my english

Comment: HI i have this problem now : syntax error, unexpected ' " '  from : $incStatement = ($this->tarea != NULL) "where t2.tar_nombre = '.$this->tarea.'":"";

Comment: Sorry update the following $incStatement = ($this->tarea != NULL) "where t2.tar_nombre = '.$this->tarea.'":""; to

Comment: $incStatement = ($this->tarea != NULL) ? "where t2.tar_nombre = '.$this->tarea.'":"";

Comment: also updated code to encounter for the forgotten "?"

Comment: Did this help with your question, or is there any issues outstanding on this, if so let me know.